# jQuery show() list elements as inline-block

Tags: jquery

I want to show 3 li first as inline-block then load more with the "Load more" link, also inline-block li elements. What I have now is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/dvm3qskg/

The thing is I am using `css("display", "inline-block")` instead of show() because when I use `show()` my list elements are `display:list-type` and I want to use `show()` because I would like to add some animation to it. Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not then using `span` instead? Anyway, sounds like XY problem imho

Comment: What kind of animation you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `faeIn` and `fadeOut` effect for animation 
I have done by editing your script, refer below code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').fadeIn('slow').css("display","inline-block");
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').fadeIn('slow').css("display","inline-block");
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').fadeOut('slow').css("display","none");
    });
});
```

Hope it helps you.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `inline-block` to `li` elements in CSS (`show` and `hide` methods will remember this value):

CSS:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#myList li {
  display: none;
}
#loadMore {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
  color: black;
}
#showLess {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#showLess:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  size_li = $("#myList li").size();
  x = 3;
  $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show('500');
  $('#loadMore').click(function() {
    x = (x + 5 <= size_li) ? x + 5 : size_li;
    $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show('500');
  });
  $('#showLess').click(function() {
    x = (x - 5 < 0) ? 3 : x - 5;
    $('#myList li').not(':lt(' + x + ')').hide('500');
  });
});
```

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dvm3qskg/7/)