# Unset to "display: flex" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, flexbox, header, navbar, unset

I would like to create a header/navbar, that is not visible in the first place,
but appears as soon as the user scrolls down.

I´m using following CSS on my header:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px){
#header {
    display:none;   
    width:100%!important;
}
}
```

and jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
      
      if ( $ (window).width() > 1024) {
       
        if ( $ (window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
            $ ('#header').fadeIn();
          } else {
            $ ('#header').fadeOut();
             }
      }
    });
});
```

So far it works, but unfortunately the header flexbox container
will now unset to "display: block;" instead of "display: flex;".
How can I unset it to "display: flex;" so that the layout is not messed up?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Add `.css("display", "flex")` after `.fadeIn()`.   See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38247383/2181514)

Comment: Why don't you add another div inside the header with flex properties? jQuery will indeed change it to display block.

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?  I seem to recall this was a problem in 1.3(ish) but 3.3.1 (at least as that's on jsfiddle) *restores* the correct `display:` when using fadeIn/show etc:  https://jsfiddle.net/vpw8ton9/ **Edit** nevermind, you don't *restore* it because by default it's `display:none` - there's no way jquery can know what you want if it's not previously set.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Really apprecitate it. The first answer worked out very well.